# I decided to extend my stay in Singapore and change my next country of destination, what should I do about the SG Arrival Card?

Tags: filipino-citizens, singapore, philippines, visas-on-arrival, jetstar

I am already here in Singapore and submitted my SG Arrival Card but I decided to extend for additional two (2) days and change my next destination, what should I do?

Comment: How many days of granted stay? Are you trying to stay more than 30 days?

Comment: I am allowed for 30 days free entry-visa. Initially my travel is only for 3D2N but I want to extend for additional 2 days.

Comment: That's no problem. As long as you leave within 30 days, Singapore is happy.

Answer (score 3):

In the Singapore arrival card that you received by email, there is a Last day allowed in Singapore. You can stay still that day without any issues.

If you want to extend beyond that, you can apply here - https://www.ica.gov.sg/enter-depart/extend_short_stay . The stay extension is free upto 90 days.

Say, if you intended to stay one week here and entered with documentation for one week, staying additional few days is ok, as you are by default granted for 30 days. You can change next destination as you wish. No problem at all.

Comment: +1. IIRC the Arrival Card does not even ask you about your next destination, so no issues changing that.

Comment: @lambshaanxy the Arrival Card for non-residents [does ask for the "next city / port of disembarkation after Singapore"](https://youtu.be/hhq4ffp-qOc?t=113), though I very much doubt even Singapore will notice or care if your plans change in this regard.

Comment: @mlc I have changed it before. No questions asked.

Comment: @mlc Ah, looks like the non-resident form is (unsurprisingly) different then.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Residents don't have form. Scan the passport and run for grab. :D

Comment: @AnishSheela Everybody has to fill out the SG Arrival Card for now, even Singaporeans :/

Comment: @lambshaanxy Oh! I haven't been outside SG since my second arrival. Previously, forms were not needed for residents, right?

Comment: @AnishSheela Correct, this is a post-COVID thing and hopefully temporary.  It's already not needed at land borders.